# Create an array of objects with multiple properties using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to create an array of objects that has two properties `name` and  `shade`?

```js
[{
    "name": "black",
    "shade": "dark"
  }, {
    "name": "white",
    "shade": "light"
  },
  {
    "name": "red",
    "shade": "dark"
  }, {
    "name": "blue",
    "shade": "dark"
  },
  {
    "name": "yellow",
    "shade": "light"
  }
]
```

I have two different arrays now.

```
name = ["black","white","red","blue","yellow"]
shade = ["dark","light","dark","dark","light"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I was actually looking for the opposite of this .ie. I have an array of objects and want to split the 2 properties into 2 different arrays. Any idea please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `map`

```
var output = name.map( (s, i) => ({name : s, shade : shade[i]}) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var name1 = ["black","white","red","blue","yellow"];

var shade = ["dark","light","dark","dark","light"];

var output = name1.map( (s, i) => ({name : s, shade : shade[i]}) );

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Thank you.....if array is if different size and if i want to map first element of property to third element of shade property how would u do that

Answer (score 1):

```
var new_array = [];
// assuming the arrays have the same length
for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
    new_array.push({name: name[i], shade: shade[i]});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()`:

```js
let names = ["black", "white", "red", "blue", "yellow"],
    shades = ["dark", "light", "dark", "dark", "light"];

let merge = (a1, a2) => names.map((n, i) => ({name: n, shade: shades[i]}));

console.log(merge(names, shades));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a helper object for addressing the types.

```js
var names = [ "black", "white", "red", "blue", "yellow"],
    shades = ["dark", "light", "dark", "dark", "light"],
    temp = { name: names, shade: shades },
    result = Object
        .keys(temp)
        .reduce(
            (r, k) => (temp[k].forEach((v, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || {})[k] = v), r),
            []
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```